# symfony2: Notice: Undefined index: locale in .../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.php line 71

Tags: session, symfony

After downgrading* symfony-standard to 2.0.4 I get following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: locale in .../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.php line 71
```

Any ideas?

- yes downgrading, cause I couldn't manage to get rid of the bundle incompatibillities I had with HEAD of symfony-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared my browser cache. that worked!

Comment: thx, didn't notice the locale was stored in the session before 2.1 and therefor not present. Btw. it's the cookies you have to remove.